# How to move from OOP object composition to FP function composition in C#

Tags: c#, functional-programming, functions, higher-order-functions

I have been working for a few weeks on a new web project and I am realizing that all I am doing is basically calculations and transformations on data, and that most of my classes do not contain any state and could perfectly be turned into static classes with static methods. Therefore I am thinking that this could be a nice opportunity to architect the application following the functional programming paradigm. I have first done some research on the Internet to read about the experiences of other people trying something similar and I found a nice [blog entry](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.nl/2015/08/c-program-entirely-with-static-methods.html) with some interesting ideas.

However, I am wondering how I should deal with the situation where you have multiple levels of nested function calls. I will try to give a simple example to show what I mean, first in OOP and then in FP.

In OOP I usually try to create simple classes that build functionality on layers by using composition. Something like this:

```
public class ClassLevel1
{
    private readonly IClassLevel2 _objLevel2;

    public ClassLevel1(IClassLevel2 objLevel2)
    {
        _objLevel2 = objLevel2;
    }

    public int FuncLevel1(int param1, int param2)
    {
        // Some operations here
        var res = _objLevel2.FuncLevel2(param1) + param2;
        // Some more operations here with the 'res'
        return result;
    }  
}

public class ClassLevel2
{
    private readonly IClassLevel3 _objLevel3;

    public ClassLevel2(IClassLevel3 objLevel3)
    {
        _objLevel3 = objLevel3;
    }

    public int FuncLevel2(int param1)
    {
        // Some operations here
        var res = _objLevel3.FuncLevel3(param1);
        // Some more operations here with the 'res'
        return result;
    }  
}
```

Then I can rely on dependency injection to build the instances and I can take advantage of any mocking framework to very easily unit test each class.

Now let's imagine that I would like to move to FP and let's say that we have a function `FuncLevel1` that internally calls `FuncLevel2`, which internally uses a third function `FuncLevel3`. One of my main goals would be to structure the code in such a way that I can easily mock each function in my unit tests. For example, the code would like this:

```
public static int FuncLevel1(
    Func<Func<int, int>, int, int> FuncLevel2,
    Func<int, int> FuncLevel3,
    int param1,
    int param2)
{
    // Some operations here
    var res = FuncLevel2(FuncLevel3, param1) + param2;
    // Some more operations here with 'res'
    return result;  
}

public static int FuncLevel2(
    Func<int, int> FuncLevel3,
    int param1)
{
    // Some operations here
    var res = FuncLevel3(param1);
    // Some more operations here with 'res'
    return result;  
}
```

Then function `FuncLevel1` is called like:

```
var res = FuncLevel1(FuncLevel2, FuncLevel3, 5, 10);
```

The advantage of this structure is that I can mock the functions `FuncLevel2` and `FuncLevel3` if I want to unit test `FuncLevel1` and `FuncLevel2` respectively.

In a simple scenario I realize that you could write the code instead as:

```
var res3 = FuncLevel3(5);
var res2 = FuncLevel2(res3) + 10;
var res1 = FuncLevel1(res2);
```

But it is easy imagine that there may be other (more complex) situations where it is not possible to solve the problem like this.

In case you have deeply nested function calls, then passing all the required functions at the lower levels all the way from the top can produce some cumbersome code. Therefore I am very interested in reading about alternatives to better handle a scenario like this.

Comment: Tell me what is the problem again?  Just say it in 15 words or less (it's the reason your post title is terrible).  Start with the 3 words "How do I" or "How can I".

Comment: Have a look at *extension methods.*   Extension methods are a great way to tame some of this complexity.

Comment: Naming temporary results to make an expression more maintainable is perfectly okay. Just don't reuse the variable. Interesting things start when you don't know how the functions you pass are combined by `FuncLevel1`, and cannot just reproduce it locally.

Comment: Consider whether you need your function to vary so much. If you are always going to call `FuncLevel1` with `FuncLevel2` and `FuncLevel3`, there's no need to have them as parameters.

Comment: You are on the right track and realize that functional programming styles have too many good things to ignore.  Talking about re-usability and Single Responsibility principles!  As prior response suggested you can go one layer deeper using Extension methods which are even better.  Nested Functions are excellent decorators especially when using callbacks as you've shown.  For me, today, I focus way more on functions than anything else... "Favor composition over inheritance"

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I have updated the question to explain better my dilemma. I could use extension methods or eliminate the functions as parameters, but then I think I will lose the flexibility to mock the functions in the unit tests. Ideally I would like to have some like dependency injection for functions and a library to handle that for me. I wonder how they deal with this in Haskell or F#...

Comment: @CarlosRodriguez You might want to explain why you need to mock the functions in unit tests. If you are unit testing at the level of individual functions, you may be over-engineering the testing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a functional language like F#, you could take advantage of [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). That is, `FuncLevel1` only has one function parameter, `FuncLevel2` and it already contains `FuncLevel3` inside it:

```
let funcLevel1 (funcLevel2 : int -> int) (param1 : int) (param2 : int) : int =
    let result = funcLevel2 param1 + param2;
    result

let funcLevel2 (funcLevel3 : int -> int) (param1 : int) : int =
    let result = funcLevel3 param1
    result
```

Usage:

```
let result = funcLevel1 (funcLevel2 funcLevel3) 5 10
```

In C#, you could model the functions the same way too:

```
public static int FuncLevel1(
    Func<int, int> FuncLevel2,
    int param1,
    int param2)
{
    var result = FuncLevel2(param1) + param2;
    return result;  
}
```

The question is how to perform the partial application. C# does not support it directly, but you can emulate it using lambdas:

```
var res = FuncLevel1(i => FuncLevel2(FuncLevel3, i), 5, 10);
```

Another option would be to write a helper method that does the partial application:

```
public static Func<T2, T3> PApply<T1, T2, T3>(Func<T1, T2, T3> func, T1 arg1)
{
    return arg2 => func(arg1, arg2);
}
```

But when you try to use it:

```
var res = FuncLevel1(PApply(FuncLevel2, FuncLevel3), 5, 10);
```

you get a compile time error about not being able to infer type arguments. That error is fixable, but it results in worse code than the lambda version, so I would stick with that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Using lambdas to emulate partial application is a good idea, but I wonder how would that scale if you deeply nested functions. Don't you think code will become unmanageable? Do you have any suggestions? I realize that maybe you shouldn't write your application in such a way, but I am just trying to take this idea to the limit. :-)

Comment: @CarlosRodriguez You would have to measure, but I imagine it could become a problem in code that's very performance sensitive. You could probably create a custom delegate-like type that is optimized for efficient `PApply` to work around that.